# How much does one stem cell cost?

Tags: cell-biology

I am interested in scaled price on 1 stem cell, only for educational purposes. I couldn't find any information about pure price on stem cell, only whole procedure price. So if anyone know, I'll be very appreciated.

Comment: I'll hazard a rather educated guess that nobody on the planet sells single stem cells. The problem is that single cells usually do not do well on their own and normally you order them in bulk or isolate a population yourself; there will be loss in each cell recovery step in your procedure, and one is hardly enough for any step, ever. Maybe a (fertilized) zygote... and those rapidly develop out of the one-cell stage and cannot really be easily stored. I'm sure some may exist, but are probably not commercially sold. On this basis I hope you understand that the question should rather be closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Biology in terms of SE Biology.

Comment: @David So, where can I ask it?